# Trying to use the move (mv) command, but I get "no such file or directory"

Tags: command-line

I having trouble using the move command. I have created two directories called `Cat` and `Dog`. Under `Cat` I created a file called `puppies`.

When I try to move `puppies` from `Cat` to `Dog` I get `No such file or directory`. However, when I go back and `cd Cat` and `ls -a`, it shows `puppies`. Then, I go back to my home directory and `ls -a`, and `Cat` and `Dog` are listed.

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is the exact command you used?

Comment: Most likely this will be the answer: Linux is case-sensitive.

Answer (score 11):

Some useful things to know when doing things with files:

- Linux is **case sensitive** (so `dog`, `Dog` and `DOG` are all different files)
- How commands work depends on **where you are** in the filesystem
- Based on where you are you can use **relative** or **absolute** pathnames

So, if you are in the parent directory of `Cat` and `Dog` you can use relative pathnames, like this:

```
mv Cat/puppies Dog
```

An easy mistake to make is to type the pathname starting with `/`

```
mv /Cat/puppies /Dog
```

This will give a `no such file or directory` error, because `/` is the root directory and there are no `Cat` and `Dog` directories under `/`. Have a look:

```
ls /
```

One reason for this confusion is that the system uses a helpful shortcut for the user's home directory, so instead of `/home/username/somefile` you can type `~/somefile` as the absolute pathname of `somefile` in your user's home directory, so, assuming `Cat` and `Dog` are at the top of your user's home directory, you can move `puppies` from `Cat` to `Dog` from anywhere in your filesystem with

```
mv ~/Cat/puppies ~/Dog
```

**A couple of examples using relative pathnames**

If you are in the directory `Cat`, you can move `puppies` like this

```
mv puppies ../Dog
```

`..` specifies the parent directory of the current working directory

If you are in the directory `Dog` you can move puppies like this

```
mv ../Cat/puppies .
```

`.` specifies the current working directory

To find out where you are, you can usually look at your prompt, but just to be sure, you can always check with `pwd` which stands for 'print working directory'

Answer (score 0):

The command I would use here is (assuming they are in the top level of your home directory):

```
mv ~/Cat/puppies ~/Dog/puppies
```

If the directory `puppies` contains more directories you will need to add the recursive flag `-r` which would make the command look like:

```
mv -r ~/Cat/puppies ~/Dog/puppies
```

Note the command is case sensitive.

Comment: If the OP is trying to move files in their home directory, `sudo` could most likely be omitted.

Comment: Interesting why should it be omitted ?

Comment: @Danturnip You don't need `sudo` to move files you own ie ones you created in your home directory, that is why it can be omitted. Just edit the sudos out and people will revert there votes.

Comment: the use of sudo is not needed nor recommended, please remove from your answer. (plus Sudo isn't even a command but obviously sudo is & shouldn't be used in this case. Users don't need or want root owning files in their $HOME

Comment: The OP is most likely the owner of their own home directory. `sudo` would move the files as `root`, which is a bad idea, see the explanation of the *Principle of least privilege* at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege. If the OP instead wanted to move, say, `/cats/puppies/` to `/dog/puppies`, `sudo` would most likely be required. To the OP: only if the command fails because of `permission denied`, try with `sudo`.

Comment: besides that ... it would be "sudo" not "Sudo".

Comment: Well I learned something new today, apologies for the misleading answer I wasn't aware moving as root changed the file owner to root!